# Efficient way to count the number of appearances of a digit in a number

Tags: c#, performance

I need to count the number of times a single digit (not 0) appears in a number (positive integer) of varying length.
The obvious solution is to convert the number to a string, the digit to a character and iterate over the string to count the number of times the character appears in the string.

```
static int CountDigitInString(string searchString, char digit)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < searchString.Length; i++)
    {
        if (searchString[i] == digit)
            sum++;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

The problem with this method, however, is that it is too slow for my purposes as I am running it many times.

```
public static void Run()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        CountDigitInString(i.ToString(), (char)j);
    }
}
```

After I noted that the process took too much time, the CPU sampling profiler showed me that the problem was with the conversion to string.

So, how do I efficiently count the number of times a digit (single digit only, not a number) appears in a number (of any length)?

Comment: I might be wrong but, couldn't you run separate loops on different threads, one going from start to end and the other one going form end to start?
Or even better, have "many" threads doing each a chunk of the string? Like 10 threads doing 10% each ? That would essentially divide the time by 10 times

Comment: In simple scenarios distributing and gathering results from threads is much less efficient than using serial version of code (simple loop). Just try Parallel.For or AsParallel() from linq in such simple case described above.
To test performance of this code in linq you can use SelectMany() and do conversion of number to string first and then to string array...

Comment: A Parallel loop being faster than a regular loop would almost always be true anyway. What I'd like to know is if there's a more efficient **method** to do what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is more optimized version of @shaitibber solution. It replaces one division with multiplying and returns 1 for 0,0. It is about 20% faster.

```
static int CountDigitsInString2(int number, int digit)
{
    int sum = 0;

    do
    {
        int n2 = number / 10;
        if (number - n2 * 10 == digit)
            sum++;
        number = n2;
    } while (number != 0);

    return sum;
}
```

And here is solution about three times faster than that (but does not work for 0 digit, which is not required). It precalculates results for numbers 0..9999.

```
private static int[][] cache = new int[10][];
private const int cacheSize = 10000;//or 100000

private static int[] initCache(int digit)
{
    var ca = cache[digit] = new int[cacheSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < ca.Length; ++i)
    {
        ca[i] = CountDigitsInString2(i, digit);
    }
    return ca;
}

static int CountDigitsInString3(int number, int digit)
{
    var ca = cache[digit] ?? initCache(digit);
    int sum = 0;

    while (number != 0)
    {
        int n2 = number / cacheSize;
        sum += ca[number - n2 * cacheSize];
        number = n2;
    };

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: For one thing, your brilliant manipulation of arithmetical operations for optimization get a +1 from me.  For another, although I really wanted my answer to be the accepted one and although my answer **was** much more efficient in the special case of consecutive numbers, the question was about finding an efficient way to count the number of appearances of a digit in a number, and in that sense, your way is better than mine.
  P.S. I measured it as twice as fast as the optimized version, not three times as fast

Comment: @shaitibber thank You for Your measurement. Measuring such small program is particulary tricky, it is good to see it on different systems.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way which turned out to be about 3 times as fast on average (checked using a Stopwatch):

```
static int CountDigitsInString(int number, int digit)
{
    int sum = 0;

    while (number != 0)
    {
        if (number % 10 == digit)
            sum++;
        number /= 10;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

EDIT:
I found a way which is over 4 times as fast as the one above. Before I start, note that this solution is valid **only** for cases in which you are counting appearances of a digit in **consecutive** numbers.

It occurred to me that if you counted the number of times the digit "d" appeared in a number "A", then you don't neccessarily have to recount the number of times "d" appears in "A + 1" to know what it is.
For example, if I know that the digit 3 appears 4 times in the number 35312336, I can know for a fact that it will still appear 4 times in the next consecutive number 35312337, **without actually counting**.
The reason I can do this is that the count would only change in one of three cases:
1) When the last digit of "A - 1" was a 9, "A" can change entirely due to numbers being carried over. **This is the only case in which we actually have to count** (although you could, theoretically, optimize this further by checking the numbers carried over to see if they affect the total but this strikes me as overly complicated).
2) When the last digit of "A - 1" was "d - 1", we know that the number of times "d" appears in "A" has increased by one.
3) When the last digit of "A - 1" was "d", we know that the number of times "d" appears in "A" has decreased by one.

This means that you **only have to count the appearances of "d" in "A" using arithmetical operations in one out of 10 cases!**

```
public static void Run()
{
    int digit = 1;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        int previousLastDigit = (i - 1) % 10;

        if (previousLastDigit == (digit - 1))
            count++;
        else if (previousLastDigit == 9)
            count = CountDigitsInString(i, digit);
        else if (previousLastDigit == digit)
            count--;
        Console.WriteLine(digit + " appears " + count + " times in the number " + i);
    }
}
```

The CountDigitsInString function is the one above.

Comment: I'm not sure that this will work in all cases: [see](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BwyaSD). Adding an `number = Math.Abs(number)` might help.

Comment: This doesn't work. Count `3`s in `342354251` for example returns 0. You need to truncate `number` each time you divide by zero: `number = (int)(number/10)`. Also, as pointed out in previous comment, this will not work with negative values. You need to first discard the sign taking the absolute value of `number`.

Comment: Counting 3s in 342354251 worked fine for me with the above code.
As for the negative values, I edited the question.

Comment: Woops! Sorry, I was somehow considering `number` a `double`, hence the need to truncate. Its an `int` so it works perfectly fine. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little snip with LINQ to give you another way to do it (didn't ran a stopwatch)

```
var number = 11334511;
var digit = 1;
var digitAsChar = Convert.ToChar(digit.ToString().ToLower());

// Occurence will be 4
var occurence = number.ToString().ToLower().Count(s => s == digitAsChar);
```

Comment: This was over twice as **slow** as my manual method of iterating over a string and Dr. Stitch's method.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use LINQ on string.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693025.aspx

```
static int CountDigitInString(string number, char digit)
{
   int count = number.Count(ns => ns == digit);
   return count;
}
```

Comment: while this **is** a more elegant way to go about counting the number of appearances of a character in a string, it is just as **efficient** as the original way I proposed, which was too slow for me.